# How to import Apple Mail accounts?

Tags: mail.app, email, import

I'm copying the old Mail folder over a fresh OS install.
I Copied over `~/Library/Mail` & `~/Library/Application Support/Mail`
Mails and mailboxes imported all right ( even better results than using `Import Mailboxes` menu option )
But the accounts didn't import. Where are they stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Account data should all be in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

Newtron's advice is spot on. For some account types, you will find that you'll need to import the appropriate keychain entries as well.

Comment: yeah well I re-entered the passwords, no big deal.